# Open cover of a metric space $M$ when $f(x) \neq a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in M$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

$f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, where $f(x) \neq a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in M$.

I need to prove that the collection of open sets $U$ for which either $f(x) > a$ for $x \in U$ or $f(x) < a$ for $x \in U$ is an open cover of $M$.

First, I believe that given such a continuous function, it must be that $f(x) > a, \forall x \in M$ or $f(x) < a, \forall x \in M$. However, I am not sure how to prove this without using the Intermediate Value Theorem or any mention of connectedness, as we have not yet covered that yet in class.

Second, let us say that I do assume that $f(x) > a, \forall x \in M$ or $f(x) < a, \forall x \in M$. Does the following proof show that the collection of open sets $U$ is an open cover of $M$?

Without loss of generality, suppose that $f(x) > a, \forall x \in M$. Then $x \in M \implies f(x) > a$. Fix $x \in M$. Choose an open set $U_x \subset M$ that contains $x$. It also follows that every element $x \in U_x$ is also such that $f(x) >a$. We can do this exercise for all $x \in M$. Then, it follows that $M \subset \bigcup\limits_{x \in M} U_x$, since every $x \in M$ is contained in some $U_x$ in the union. Furthermore, by construction, each $U_x$ is a subset of $M$, so $\bigcup\limits_{x \in M} U_x \subset M$. Therefore, $\bigcup\limits_{x\in M} U_x  = M$, and the set of open sets $U_x$ is an open cover of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(x) \neq a \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \in M$, $f(x)>a$ or $f(x)<a$. If $f(x)>a$, then $x\in f^{-1}(a,+\infty)$. If $f(x)<a$, then $x\in f^{-1}(-\infty,a)$.

So $M=f^{-1}(a,+\infty)\cup f^{-1}(-\infty,a)$. Since $x$ is a continuous function, both $f^{-1}(a,+\infty)$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty,a)$ are open set.